# Five images to take up full width collectively

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a site where the footer includes 5 social media thumbnail images, which are also links:

[image]

I want these images to display with a max-width of 64px (their native size), and when the width of the page shrinks to much to accommodate this, then shrink just to 20% so that all 5 images fit next to each other.

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-imgs">
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/chrisscribnermusic' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-facebook.png'></a>
    <a href='https://twitter.com/ChrisScribs' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-twitter.png'></a>
    <a href='https://soundcloud.com/chris-scribner-1' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-soundcloud.png'></a>
    <a href='https://www.youtube.com/user/ChrisScribs/feed' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-youtube.png' /></a>
    <a href='https://instagram.com/chrisscribs/' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-instagram.png'></a>
</div>
```

Right now the CSS is:

```
#footer-imgs {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#footer-imgs a {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#footer-imgs a img {
    max-width: 64px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The images simply don't want to shrink more than 64px. If the window shrinks this much, the div just expands past the width of the page (creates horizontal scrollbar). Using width: 20% didn't solve this for me either. How can I get these to shrink the way they need to?

Edit: Would just like to say thanks to everyone who tried, on what was a surprisingly difficult issue!

Comment: Think about it. You slapped 20% on that but 20% of what?

Comment: I tried setting it on both the <a> element (no effect), and on the img element (which had an effect but not the desired one, obviously). I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now and I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

It's efficient (minimal code), responsive, and makes centering – both vertical and horizontal – easy.

**CSS**

```
#footer-imgs {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    align-items: center; /* center flex items vertically */
    justify-content: space-around; /* spread flex items across container */
}

#footer-imgs a img {
    max-width: 100%; /* scale images to screen size */
    height: auto;  /* scale images to screen size */    
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2notcw09/4/ (resize window for effect)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*

Comment: That jsfiddle is actually overflowing... At least on chrome.

Comment: Chris, I revised my answer. Let me know if that effect works for you.

Comment: This is working perfectly! Thanks a tonne!! I just have one more question: I removed the "justify-content: space-around;" so that the items are grouped together, now how can I get them to be centred? I've tried a few things with no luck.

Comment: `justify-content: center`

Comment: Ahh! You are a gentle-person and a scholar. Thanks again so much for your help, it's massively appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help. Google 'justify-content'. There are 5 alignment options.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob) said, you can use a width of 20% on the img, but 20% of what? You should give your parent element a width of 100% so it knows what to fill.

HTML

```
<div id="footer-imgs">
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/chrisscribnermusic' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-facebook.png'></a>
    <a href='https://twitter.com/ChrisScribs' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-twitter.png'></a>
    <a href='https://soundcloud.com/chris-scribner-1' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-soundcloud.png'></a>
    <a href='https://www.youtube.com/user/ChrisScribs/feed' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-youtube.png' /></a>
    <a href='https://instagram.com/chrisscribs/' class='footer-img'><img src='imgs/social-instagram.png'></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer-imgs {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer-imgs a {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#footer-imgs a img {
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 64px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Correct but remind him that if he sets the parent element to 100%, then 100% of what? However, I'm not sure this completely solves his problem.

Comment: The viewport, I presume.

Comment: It would be the parent of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `#footer-imgs` `width` to `100%` , `#footer-imgs a img` `width` to `calc(20%)`

```
#footer-imgs {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer-imgs a {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#footer-imgs a img {
    max-width: 64px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: calc(20%);
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ak53nwt4/

Comment: I'm still getting the overflow on the right side with this jsfiddle. It's exactly like what I'm getting on my page. I've been trying to get it to display correctly to properly show you guys in jsfiddle but couldn't get it, but this is it. I don't know. I can't get it to work. I'm calling it -- I just can't. I'm just going to use divs with background-image css properties and links inside that expand to fill the width and height.

Comment: @Chris Is requirement to also center images in viewport ?

Comment: @Chris Did you remove the standard margin that Chrome gives to the body? I updated above fiddle and I don't have the overflow anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/ak53nwt4/3/